# Автозаполнение полей при вводе данных

Tags: запрос

Добрый день!
 Не могу реализовать следующее:

Имеется БД с таблицей:
 sh_kod - сюда заносится штрих-код
 tmc - сюда заносится наименование товара
 cena - сюда заносится цена товара

На сайте есть 5 полей: штрих-код, наименование, серийный номер, количество, цена.

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе штрих-кода вручную автоматически бы брались из БД значения, которые соответсвуют штрих-коду и заполнялось поле название товара и его цена, при этом страница не перезагружалась бы?

См. картинку ниже.

Спасибо.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика такая: на событие нажатия клавиши в текстовом поле выполнять Ajax-запрос на сервер. В этом запросе передавать введенный текст. Сервер этот текст получает, выполняет запрос в базу и возвращает найденные данные. JS-скрипт эти данные получает и заполняет форму.

Допустим, форма имеет 3 текстовых поля

```
<input type="text" name="code" />
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="price" />
```

Тогда javascript код будет таким (с учетом того, что у вас подключен jQuery на сайте):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="code"]').on('keyup', function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/items.php',
            data: {code: $input.val()},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('input[name="name"]').val(data.name);
                $('input[name="price"]').val(data.price);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

На стороне сервера вы принимаете в $_POST['code'] введенный код и выполняете запрос (предварительно отфильтровав значение в $_POST['code'] в целях защиты от инъекций):

```
$data = $db->findOne("SELECT tmc, cena FROM my_table WHERE code = '$code'");
```

И возвращаете сериализованные в JSON данные (вариант для PHP):

```
echo json_encode(array('name' => $data['tmc'], 'price' => $data['cena']));
exit();
```

В примере я все упростил, чтобы вам была понятна логика. А уже конкретная реализация зависит от того, что используется у вас на сервере. Также, перед отправкой кода, если это возможно, желательно установить проверку длины введенного текста (скажем, у вас минимальная длина кода - 8 знаков, значит пока все 8 не введены, нет смысла отправлять запрос на сервер)

Comment: Да в том-то и дело, что я понимаю логику, но реализовать это не могу. Я же не программист. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы были готовые скрипты, которые можно вставить. Или я бы мог скинуть страничку и БД, чтобы реализовать это дело. Можно за оплату.
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы не уточнили деталей (кроме структуры таблицы), а ждете готовое решение. Оно при такой постановке задачи вряд ли появится. Какой язык программирования используется на стороне сервера? Какая СУБД применяется?

Comment: @vityus, если вы

> не программист

то на этом форуме вам делать нечего. [ХэшКод не является фриланс биржей][1]. Обратитесь на любую [биржу фриланса][2].


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8
  [2]: https://www.google.by/search?q=биржа+фриланса